# SQL - How to select all columns of the field with the longest string name

Tags: sql, wildcard

I know how to find the length of the longest string of a column and how to select it. But what I can't figure out is how to query all columns

I tried this in W3School's SQL console

```
SELECT *, MAX(LEN(Address)) as MaxLengthOfAddress
FROM Customers;
```

I get this error message

> Cannot group on fields selected with '*'.

However, If I just get the maximum address length by itself it works

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(Address)) as MaxLengthOfAddress
FROM Customers;
```

I used the wildcard operator `*` because I wanted to get every column in addition to this maximum length column. I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This can easily be done using a window function

Comment: I'm actually not using one. I'm just following the tutorial from W3Schools. So I'd say regular SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the `MAX(LEN(Address))` and then use that to find records with addresses of that length.  E.g.,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Customers
WHERE  LEN(Address) = ( SELECT MAX(LEN(Address))
                        FROM   Customers );
```

You didn't tag your question with a particular RDBMS, but depending on what you are using, it's a sure bet that there are more efficient ways of doing that.  But I hope this illustrates the basic concept.

Comment: Subqueries is a brilliant solution. I myself learned about this today.

Answer (score 1):

You need a subquery in your where clause.
Try like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Customers
 WHERE LEN(Adress) >= (SELECT MAX(LEN(Address))
                         FROM Customers
                      )
;
```

Comment: The `>` in `>=` is useless. `=` is enough, there can't be any value where the length is bigger than the maximum length.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 C.*
FROM         Customers C
ORDER BY     LEN(Address) desc
```

The order by ensures that the top selection will have the max address length, while using TOP allows you to select all columns without any unnecessary complexities.

Comment: Except that syntax doesn't work in all databases and the OP didn't specify.   Also, is that going to be efficient?  Why sort a list of 2 million customers just to get the top one?

Comment: He specified that he is using W3Schools, which it will work for.  And he didn't specify that he has 2 million customers so I provided what I think is the easiest solution, not necessarily the most efficient..  At 2 million customers, I assume an aggregate subquery would still only benefit negligibly over a sort.